# Is it possible to pass OS variables to docker-compose (or stack)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, docker-swarm

I'd like to pass the result of bash-command (or cmd) or OS variable as an env to `docker-compose.yml`, is it possible or not?

For example:

> `hostname` gives me the current machine name: `ubuntu-machine-01`

and I'd like to pass it as env for docker-compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service:
    image: docker-container:latest
    environment:
      - WORKSPACE=${{hostname}}
```

P.S. Unfortunately I can't bypass arg during Docker image build phase & unable to call it inside container, so the question is about passing OS env to docker-compose via syntax of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regards to `hostname` specifically it is worth mentioning Docker Swarm supports [service template parameters.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#create-services-using-templates)

So to follow the example on a swarm, if you needed `WORKSPACE` to reflect the hostname of the node the service is running on (rather than deployed from), the following syntax would apply:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  service:
    image: docker-container:latest
    environment:
      WORKSPACE: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
```

Comment: thank you for your answer,  I'll check is lately, if it works, I guess it's a perfect solution of my problem and I accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, no. Unfortunately [Docker Compose interpolation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/12-interpolation/) only supports a limited set of features.

> Other extended shell-style features [...] are not supported by Compose.

Alternatively you can create a [`.env` file which will be used by Docker Compose to interpolate variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/), for example:

```bash
echo "HOSTNAME=$(hostname)" > .env
```

And with `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  service:
    image: docker-container:latest
    environment:
      - WORKSPACE=$HOSTNAME
```

Comment: The idea with creating `.env` file is great btw, thank you. As for now, it's the best possible solution.

Comment: As the question involved both stack and compose, it must be mentioned that `docker stack deploy` does not read .env files.